# Versioning file name and saving it to different location

Tags: c#

After the else block `Path.Combine` method combines every part and gives the file name when `Console.WriteLine(result);` is used. But it doesn't actually create the file with that name.

I want to get the *EmployeeDetails.txt* file, make a version of it (i.e. renaming the filename) and saves it to `C:\Hitory` folder.

How to achieve that?

Using `File.Move` throws `FileNotFoundexception`

```
void ModRec()       
{     
        string filename = @"C:\Current\EmployeeDetails.txt";
        string current = @"C:\Current\";
        string history = @"C:\History\";
        FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(filename);
        if (fileinfo.Exists)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(history))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(history);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tFile doesn't exist!");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Menu1();
        }
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
        var fileNamePart = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename); 
        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename); 
        var version = 0; 
        string result;
        do
        {
            version++;
            result = Path.Combine(path, fileNamePart + "_" + version + extension); 
        }
        while (File.Exists(result));
        //File.Move(current, history);
    }
```

Comment: The code makes little sense.  You call File.Move() even when the file doesn't exists.  Of course it will complain.

Comment: First, `result` will never be created. Second, `File.Move(current...)` where current is a directory??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop at the end needs to change slightly, because

```
    result = Path.Combine(path, fileNamePart + "_" + version + extension);
```

is looking in the directory where the file already is, rather than in the history directory where you want it to be, so you'll be scanning for duplicates in the wrong location. The `Path.Combine` therefore needs to reference the value of `history`:

```
    result = Path.Combine(history, fileNamePart + "_" + version + extension);
```

Secondly, you cannot use `Move` to move a file to a directory in the same way that you can from the command line, you need to specify the two parameters as filenames, so

```
 File.Move(current, history);
```

becomes

```
 File.Move(filename, result);
```

The resulting code at the end of your method should therefore look like this:

```
do
{
    version++;
    result = Path.Combine(history, fileNamePart + "_" + version + extension); 
}
while (File.Exists(result));
File.Move(filename, result);
```

Incidentally, where you test whether the file already exists, you simply call `Menu1` and then carry on. Can you guarantee that that will ensure that the next thing that the user does will create a valid file? I'm guessing that it most likely cannot guarantee that, so you should exit your method at that point, or perhaps put the remainder of the body inside the `fileinfo.Exists` block.

That leaves the desirability of invoking a menu from inside this method, but that's a design question outside of the scope of what you've asked here.

Comment: It also changes the file name in the Current folder EmployeeDetails.txt to EmployeeDetails_1.txt and copy the file to History folder. I don't want to change the file name in the Current folder.

Comment: Your original code did that, it's true, but this answer does not - it simply moves it from the `current` folder to the `history` folder, which is what you said you wanted to achieve. However, if you're now saying that you want to **copy** the file to the history folder, then you should write a `FileCopy` method which takes source and destination file names, and call that in place of `File.Move`.

Comment: Thanks! @ClickRick! 'File.Copy' worked. Problem Solved.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
void ModRec()       
{     
        string filename = @"C:\Current\EmployeeDetails.txt";
        string current = @"C:\Current\";
        string history = @"C:\History\";
        FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(filename);
        if (fileinfo.Exists)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(history))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(history);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tFile doesn't exist!");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Menu1();
        }
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
        var fileNamePart = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename); 
        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename); 
        var version = 0; 
        string result;
        do
        {
            version++;
            result = Path.Combine(history, fileNamePart + "_" + version + extension); 
        }
        while (File.Exists(result));
        File.Move(filename, result);
    }
```

Comment: It also changes the file name in the Current folder EmployeeDetails.txt to EmployeeDetails_1.txt and copy the file to History folder.
I don't want to change the file name in the Current folder

Comment: This code moves C:\Current\EmployeeDetails.txt to C:\History\EmployeeDetails_<number>.txt. Note that not only the line with `File.Move(...` has been changed but also the `result = ...` line to `result = Path.Combine(history, fileNamePart + "_" + version + extension);`

Answer (score -2):

`Path.Combine()` does not touch filesystem at all. No files/folders would be ever crated.

Try `File.Move(filename, history);`. That is, instead of `current`, which is a directory, move the file (assuming `filename` is a full path).

Comment: That will not work because the second argument to File.Move() needs to be the path to the destination file not to the destination directory. Furthermore this would ignore the whole versioning code.